# Inserting a new item into an ascending ordered linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Below is my implementation of an insert method for an ASC linked-list which inserts a `PQueueItem` object into a linked list of type `PQueueItem` based upon their priority.

I basically check to see, in terms of priority, if the item to be inserted is greater than the current item and smaller than the next item, and if it is, inserts it. If it's equal to the next item, put them in alphabetical order. If it's smaller than the current item, put it before it. If it's greater than both the current and next item, traverse the list until it satisfies one of the other checks.

Is this an appropriate/efficient way of implementing an insertion? Non-code ideas would be awesome if you think my idea is both:

1. Incorrect
2. Inefficient.

Cheers!

```
public void insert(T data, int priority) {
        if(order == ORDER.ASC)
        {
            //current item
            PQueueItem<T> temp = head;

            while(temp.getNext() != null)
            {
                //is inserted item greater than current item
                if(priority > temp.getPriority())
                {
                    //is inserted item smaller than next item
                    if(priority < temp.getNext().getPriority())
                    {
                         //create and insert new item, reassign links in the list
                         PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                         newPQ.setNext(temp.getNext());
                         temp.setNext(newPQ);

                    }
                    //check to see if priority equates to the next item's priority
                    else if(priority == temp.getNext().getPriority())
                    {
                        //is new item's data alphabetically greater than the next item's data
                        if(((String)data).compareToIgnoreCase((String)temp.getNext().getData()) > 0)
                        {
                             PQueueItem<T> nextPQ = temp.getNext();
                             PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                             newPQ.setNext(nextPQ.getNext());
                             nextPQ.setNext(newPQ);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                            newPQ.setNext(temp.getNext());
                            temp.setNext(newPQ);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //iterate current item
                        temp = head.getNext();
                    }
                } 
                //if item to be inserted is smaller than the current item
                else if(priority < temp.getPriority())
                {
                     PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(temp.getData(), temp.getPriority());
                     newPQ.setNext(temp.getNext());
                     temp.setData(data);
                     temp.setPriority(priority);
                }
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            //code for DESC             
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is a working piece of code, maybe you question would be better suited for [SO Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Here it is mostly about 'finding problems' and such

Comment: I'm not sure this works, I'm merely presenting it as a possible solution. Apologies for the poor phrasing of the question!

Comment: If you are not sure that it works, you should make up some testcases and code them ;)

Comment: You present a valid point! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What captures attention is:

- there is a dummy head node.

First a compare method makes sence:

```
private int compare(T data, int priority, PQueueItem<T> pq) {
    return -1 or 0 or 1;
}
```

Then without a dummy node for the head:

```
    PQueueItem<T> prior = null;
    PQueueItem<T> current = head;

    // Walk to the insertion point:
    while (current != null) {
        int comparison = compare(data, priority, current);
        if (comparison >= 0) {
            if (comparison == 0) {
                return; // No insert?
            }
            break;
        }
        prior = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    // Create the link:
    PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
    newPQ.setNext(current);

    if (prior == null) {
        head = newPQ;
    } else {
        prior.setNext(newPQ);
    }
```

Comment: So in the while loop you find the insertion point and the code to create the link happens regardless, clever! It's reassuring that you use the same sort of technique as I do too.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while, but there is something like logarithmic search, which could increase the speed of your implementation a great time (yours now linearly scales with the size of the list, logarithmic scales logarithmically with the size of the list (to understand what it means, on 1000000000 elements log(1000000000) roughtly is 20, pathetically small).

The algorithm: you start with your whole list, and cut it in half. Your element to insert takes place in exactly one of these halves. You choose the correct one, and cut that in half too. You keep doing this, until the part of the list you look at has at most 2 elements. Then you know where to put your element to insert. Implementation is usually two variables holding indexes, and in each iteration moving one of them to the half of what you currently look at.

Each step halvens your elements to process, meaning you end up with inserting your value at most logarithmic complexity of time.

Also, don't expect any better solution, logarithmic is hard to beat. If you want "instant" inserting, you need a different structure.

Comment: This is actually called Binary Search. http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch

Comment: My teacher called it logarithmic, and it's hard to argue about the accuracy of this name, but, whatever :D

Comment: BS doesn't work on a linked list because each element only has a link to the element that succeeds it. Thus to reach the end of the list, the only way is to traverse the whole list! Thus O(n)

Comment: Yes, that's true. I think it's safe to say then, that there is no way to scale it up. You can maybe save checkpoints of your list, so you can "quickly" run throught them to see where it's best to start the search, but that doesn't reduce time complexity at all.